# Git submodule not able to add sub folder

Tags: git, github

I've a Github project and I want to add submodule like following
[How to link folder from a git repo to another repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554810/how-to-link-folder-from-a-git-repo-to-another-repo/36554930)

when I run the command

```
git submodule add https://github.com/expressjs/express
```

it works

But when I run

```
git submodule add https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/lib
```

I got error not found , I want to add to my repository only sub folder and not all the repository, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not add only a sub-folder, because it is not a repository but just a part of the repository. `git submodule` is for mounting one repository inside another.

One possible alternative:
Take the sub-folder that you want to use, split it out into a stand-alone repository, and then embed it into both projects (repositories) via submodules.
You can maintain the commit history of this folder as well while making it a standalone repo using `git filter-branch`.

Detailed Description:
https://blog.github.com/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/#switching-to-submodules