# href to PDF stored on GitHub repository

Tags: html, github, pdf, github-pages

I'm building a personal page with GitHub Pages and I would like to have a link that displays some PDF files on browser.

The PDF files are on a *private* repository with the following structure:

```
PDF-Repository
|__ Folder1
|   |__ file11.notpdf
|   |__ file12.pdf
|__ Folder2
|   |__ file21.notpdf
|   |__ file22.pdf
```

I couldn't use `href` to link to the repository files directly because it's private.

Neither I can copy the PDF files on the GH Pages repository manually since the PDF-Repository (and PDF files therein) gets updated regularly.

Is there a way I can include those files on the GH Pages repository so that , every time the PDF-Repository gets updated, there is an updated version on the GH Pages repository?

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554810/how-to-link-folder-from-a-git-repo-to-another-repo?noredirect=1&lq=1. I will try and comment on the results.